# Executing init.el file to load journal

Tags: org-mode, org-journal

I have this configuration init.el file:

```lisp
    ;; for org-journal
    (setq org-journal-dir "~/Desktop/doctorado")
    (setq org-journal-date-format "%A, %d %B %Y")
    (setq org-journal-file-type 'yearly)
    (setq org-file-format "Diary %Y")
    (require 'org-journal)
    
    ;; package manager
    (require 'package)
    (add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
    
    ;; package initialization
    (package-initialize)
```

I want to open my journal with `C-c C-j` when opening emacs. However now I have to open `init.el` and do `M-x ev-b` before it works.

Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Comment: What is the path of your init.el file? How are you starting emacs? Are you on Windows? MacOS? Linux?

Comment: @NickD I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. I start emacs from a desktop shortcut. The path of the init.el file is ~/.emacs.d/init.el

Comment: After you restart emacs, what does `ESC ESC : (featurep 'org-journal)` say in the echo area?

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm wondering if the init.el file you show above is loaded at all. It should be in which case `(featurep 'org-journal)` should say `t` - if that's the case, the next step is to see what `C-c C-j` is bound to - say `C-h c C-c C-j` and see if it is what you expect. But if the `featurep` call says `nil`, then the file is not loaded at all: it may be that some other file is loaded first and this one is ignored - see [Init](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File) for details.

Comment: Unless you're using Emacs 27+, you can't load a non-standard package (which is what `org-journal` seems to be) *before* you've initialised the package manager.  You should be seeing an error if that's the issue, though, and you haven't quoted one.  What does `emacs --debug-init` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of what NickD and phils suggested did the trick. package-initialization should be up in the configuration file.

```
;; package initialization
(package-initialize)

;; for org-journal
(setq org-journal-dir "~/Desktop/doctorado")
(setq org-journal-date-format "%A, %d %B %Y")
(setq org-journal-file-type 'yearly)
(setq org-file-format "Diary %Y")
(require 'org-journal)

;; package manager
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
```

I also wasn't using the init.el configuration file but the .emacs file. I erased one of them and then it worked.